# A misunderstanding about jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I have a misunderstanding about this line:

```
$('<div></div>').prependTo('body').attr('id', 'overlay');
```

Can I get explanation about this part of the line:

```
$('<div></div>')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$('<div></div>')` creates an empty DIV element, could be write `$('<div/>')`  This is relevant DOC that you should have read: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('<div></div>')` creates an empty `div` element in memory; it doesn't actually add it to the DOM yet. `.prependTo('body')` adds it at the top of the page.

So, the code goes like this:

```
$('<div></div>') // create an empty div element
    .prependTo('body') // add it at the top of the body
    .attr('id', 'overlay'); // give it the id overlay
```

By the way, we call them "lines," not "rows." :)

Answer (score 6):

It will add `<div></div>` to the `body` tag having `id = overlay`

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

We can create content and insert it into several elements at once:

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).prependTo( ".inner" );
```

Each inner  element gets this new content:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Test</p>
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Test</p>
    Goodbye
  </div>
</div>
```

Another attempt to explain

```
    whatever you write here                  will be added here  
$( "<p>Hello its me going to be added</p>" ).prependTo( ".inner" );
```

[See this](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)

Answer (score 5):

When you call jQuery with some HTML markup, it will create HTML elements using the document.createElement functions and return them wrapped in a jQuery object. It is intelligent enough, that you don't even have to close the tags if you simply want to create a tag. For example

```
$('<div>')
```

Would do exactly the same thing. However, if you wanted to create more complex HTML, you can .e.g.

```
$('<div><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></div>')
```

Will create a div with a link inside it that points to Google